# how to check whether a not-rendered object is in camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just started learning Unity and encountered some problems.

Here I have a prefab object `ParticleAlly` with a parent `ParticleAllies`. The parent object rotates itself, and `ParticleAlly` rotates too, like a planet and satellites.

Besides, I also want to regenerate each `ParticleAlly` as soon as it is out of the camera. Then they are in different orbits with only the same angular velocity but in different positions. When it gets into and then get out of the camera, do that again.

The problem is, some `ParticleAlly` appeared in the middle of the camera directly after they are regenerated. I tried to let them not rendered until they get into the camera from outside. But it seems that `SpriteRenderer.isvisible` is true only when `SpriteRenderer.enabled` is true, so I cannot get know when to render them again. Then I tried to judge by position, but I don't know why it doesn't work at all.

I'm totally confused and wasted a whole morning on that. Sorry for my inaccurate description and term using.

It would be appreciated if you could provide me a solution and tell me something about `Update()`, the rendering, the position/localposition in rotation etc.

```
// in ParticleAlly
void Update() {
        //Debug.Log(trans.localPosition.y);
        if(trans.position.y <= globalSettings.RotationLocationY) {
            Debug.Log("Under");
            if(!isRefreshed) {
                refresh();
            }
            sRender.enabled = true;
        }
        else {
            if(sRender.isVisible) {
                isRefreshed = false;
            }
        }
}

/// <summary>
/// Regenerate the particle
/// </summary>
void refresh() {
        isRefreshed = true;

        float height = Random.value * 3;
        trans.localPosition = (new Vector3(0f, globalSettings.RotationLocationY - height, 0f));
        //trans.RotateAround(trans.parent.localPosition, new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f), globalSettings.getDegree() * Random.value);
        trans.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, globalSettings.getDegree() * Random.value));

        //sRender.enabled = false;
}

// in ParticleAllies
void Update() {
       trans.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, globalSettings.getDegree()));
}
```

It's my first time asking here, the tabs are somehow broken in the code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with [`Renderer.isVisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html) is that

- As you already noted it only can be `true` if the renderer is enabled
- It can stay `true` even if the object is not visible itself but has some visual influence on the rendering (such as e.g. shadows)

---

In case the position would be enough you could simply use e.g.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    pulic static bool IsInFrustum(this Camera camera, Vector3 worldPoint)
    {
        var screenPos = camera.WoldToscreenPoint(worldPoint);
        return screenPos.z >= camera.nearClipPlane
               && screenPos.z <= camera.farClipPlane
               && screenPos.x >= 0
               && screenPos.x <= Screen.width
               && screenPos.y >= 0
               && screenPos.y <= Screen.height;
    }

    public static bool sInFrustum(this Vector3 worldPoint, Camera camera)
    {
        return camera.IsInFrustum(worldPoint);
    }
}
```

and would do e.g.

```
someRenderer.enabled = yourCamera.IsInFrustum(someRenderer.transform.position);
```

or also

```
someRenderer.enabled = someRenderer.transform.position.IsInFrustum(yourCamera);
```

---

If a single position is not enough, you can get the camera frustum planes using [`GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html) and then check if some [`Bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) e.g. the [`Renderer.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) fall within those using [`GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html).

Bounds are not completely accurate always of course but are probably the best approximation you can get.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsInFrustum(this Renderer renderer, Camera camera)
    {
        var planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(camera);
        return GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, renderer.bounds);
    }

    public static bool IsInFrustum(this Camera camera, Renderer renderer)
    {
        return renderer.IsVisibleFrom(camera);
    }
}
```

You can now either use on your camera e.g.

```
someRenderer.enabled = yourCamera.IsInFrustum(someRenderer);
```

or also

```
someRenderer.enabled = someRenderer.IsInFrustum(yourCamera);
```